# nested subreport throws net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Resource not found at

Tags: jasper-reports

I am trying to create a report that has a subreport and this sub has another one.
the problem is when I try to create it **I get net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Resource not found at: sub-sub-report.jasper**
I can call the sub-sub directly from the app, setting its parameters and it shows up (the file is there!), but when it is called from the main doesn't work.

All files are in src/main/java/resources/reports

Using JasperStudio 6.21, jdk11, Vaadin23
The reports were original created with JasperStudio 6.6.0, now we updated almost every dependency, so I downloaded the latest JasperStudio and recompiled the 3 reports. Removing the sub-subreport makes the main show up with its sub. I set the log to TRACE trying to find out any previous error but nothing, it goes straight to "not found at..."

stacktrace

> INFO:   2024-02-28 22:48:51,538 ERROR fill.JRFillSubreport [] - Fill 1: exception
> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Resource not found at: Items2.jasper.
> at net.sf.jasperreports.repo.RepositoryUtil.getResourceFromLocation(RepositoryUtil.java:158) ~[jasperreports-6.21.0.jar:6.21.0-4f56c4f36cd19e17675219a9ac4692d5f0f13b06]
> at net.sf.jasperreports.repo.RepositoryUtil.getReport(RepositoryUtil.java:117) ~[jasperreports-6.21.0.jar:6.21.0-4f56c4f36cd19e17675219a9ac4692d5f0f13b06]
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.loadReport(JRFillSubreport.java:480) ~[jasperreports-6.21.0.jar:6.21.0-4f56c4f36cd19e17675219a9ac4692d5f0f13b06]
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.loadReportSource(JRFillSubreport.java:445) ~[jasperreports-6.21.0.jar:6.21.0-4f56c4f36cd19e17675219a9ac4692d5f0f13b06]
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.getReportSource(JRFillSubreport.java:400) ~[jasperreports-6.21.0.jar:6.21.0-4f56c4f36cd19e17675219a9ac4692d5f0f13b06]
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluateReportSource(JRFillSubreport.java:368) ~[jasperreports-6.21.0.jar:6.21.0-4f56c4f36cd19e17675219a9ac4692d5f0f13b06]
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluateSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:506) ~[jasperreports-6.21.0.jar:6.21.0-4f56c4f36cd19e17675219a9ac4692d5f0f13b06]
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluate(JRFillSubreport.java:360) ~[jasperreports-6.21.0.jar:6.21.0-4f56c4f36cd19e17675219a9ac4692d5f0f13b06]
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:383) ~[jasperreports-6.21.0.jar:6.21.0-4f56c4f36cd19e17675219a9ac4692d5f0f13b06]
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:548) ~[jasperreports-6.21.0.jar:6.21.0-4f56c4f36cd19e17675219a9ac4692d5f0f13b06]
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2614) ~[jasperreports-6.21.0.jar:6.21.0-4f56c4f36cd19e17675219a9ac4692d5f0f13b06]
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:837) ~[jasperreports-6.21.0.jar:6.21.0-4f56c4f36cd19e17675219a9ac4692d5f0f13b06]
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:276) ~[jasperreports-6.21.0.jar:6.21.0-4f56c4f36cd19e17675219a9ac4692d5f0f13b06]
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:119) ~[jasperreports-6.21.0.jar:6.21.0-4f56c4f36cd19e17675219a9ac4692d5f0f13b06]
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:631) ~[jasperreports-6.21.0.jar:6.21.0-4f56c4f36cd19e17675219a9ac4692d5f0f13b06]
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseReportFiller.fill(BaseReportFiller.java:416) ~[jasperreports-6.21.0.jar:6.21.0-4f56c4f36cd19e17675219a9ac4692d5f0f13b06]
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.fillSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:826) ~[jasperreports-6.21.0.jar:6.21.0-4f56c4f36cd19e17675219a9ac4692d5f0f13b06]
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRSubreportRunnable.run(JRSubreportRunnable.java:61) ~[jasperreports-6.21.0.jar:6.21.0-4f56c4f36cd19e17675219a9ac4692d5f0f13b06]
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.AbstractThreadSubreportRunner.run(AbstractThreadSubreportRunner.java:221) ~[jasperreports-6.21.0.jar:6.21.0-4f56c4f36cd19e17675219a9ac4692d5f0f13b06]
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[?:?]
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[?:?]
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]

INFO:   2024-02-28 22:48:51,540 ERROR server.DefaultErrorHandler [] -
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Resource not found at: Items2.jasper.
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.prepare(JRFillSubreport.java:969) ~[jasperreports-6.21.0.jar:6.21.0-4f56c4f36cd19e17675219a9ac4692d5f0f13b06]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.prepareElements(JRFillElementContainer.java:542) ~[jasperreports-6.21.0.jar:6.21.0-4f56c4f36cd19e17675219a9ac4692d5f0f13b06]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:453) ~[jasperreports-6.21.0.jar:6.21.0-4f56c4f36cd19e17675219a9ac4692d5f0f13b06]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:428) ~[jasperreports-6.21.0.jar:6.21.0-4f56c4f36cd19e17675219a9ac4692d5f0f13b06]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2616) ~[jasperreports-6.21.0.jar:6.21.0-4f56c4f36cd19e17675219a9ac4692d5f0f13b06]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:837) ~[jasperreports-6.21.0.jar:6.21.0-4f56c4f36cd19e17675219a9ac4692d5f0f13b06]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:276) ~[jasperreports-6.21.0.jar:6.21.0-4f56c4f36cd19e17675219a9ac4692d5f0f13b06]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:119) ~[jasperreports-6.21.0.jar:6.21.0-4f56c4f36cd19e17675219a9ac4692d5f0f13b06]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:631) ~[jasperreports-6.21.0.jar:6.21.0-4f56c4f36cd19e17675219a9ac4692d5f0f13b06]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:214) ~[jasperreports-6.21.0.jar:6.21.0-4f56c4f36cd19e17675219a9ac4692d5f0f13b06]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:200) ~[jasperreports-6.21.0.jar:6.21.0-4f56c4f36cd19e17675219a9ac4692d5f0f13b06]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:548) ~[jasperreports-6.21.0.jar:6.21.0-4f56c4f36cd19e17675219a9ac4692d5f0f13b06]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperRunManager.runToPdf(JasperRunManager.java:352) ~[jasperreports-6.21.0.jar:6.21.0-4f56c4f36cd19e17675219a9ac4692d5f0f13b06]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(JasperRunManager.java:785) ~[jasperreports-6.21.0.jar:6.21.0-4f56c4f36cd19e17675219a9ac4692d5f0f13b06]

Answer (score 0):

well.. the error was simple, I forgot to pass the SUBREPORT_DIR parameter to the sub report, so it can point to the right path